# R - Split String with conditions

Tags: r, string, if-statement, split, conditional-statements

I have a string splitting related problem. I have a huge amount of files, which names are structures like this:

```
filenames = c("NO2_Place1_123_456789.dat", "NO2_Nice_Place_123_456789.dat", "NO2_Nice_Place_123_456789.dat", "NO2_Place2_123_456789.dat")
```

I need to extract the Stationnames, e.g. Place1, Nice_Place1 and so on. Its either "Place" and a number or "Nice_Place" and a number.

I tried this to get the stationnames for "Place" and a number and it works geat, but this doesnt give me the correct name in case of "Nice_Place"...because it handles it as 2 words.

```
Station = strsplit(filenames[1], "_")[[1]][2] #Works
Station = strsplit(filenames[2], "_")[[1]][2] #Doesnt work
```

My idea is now to use if...else. So If the Stationname in the example above is "Nice", add the 3rd part of the stringsplit with an underscore. Unfortunatley I am totally new to this if else condition.

Can somebody please help?

EDIT:

Expected output:

```
Station = strsplit(filenames[1], "_")[[1]][2] #Station = Place
Station = strsplit(filenames[2], "_")[[1]][2] #Station = Nice -- not correct I want to have "Nice_Place"
```

So When I get

```
Station = strsplit(filenames[2], "_")[[1]][2] #Station = Nice
```

I want to add a condition, that if Station is "Nice" it should add `strsplit(filenames[2], "_")[[1]][3]` with an underscore!

EDIT2:

I found now a way to get what I want:

```
filenames = c("NO2_Place1_123_456789.dat", "NO2_Nice_Place1_123_456789.dat", "NO2_Nice_Place2_123_456789.dat", "NO2_Place2_123_456789.dat")

Station = strsplit(filenames[2], "_")[[1]][2]

if (Station == "Nice"){

  Station = paste(Station, strsplit(filenames[2], "_")[[1]][3], sep = "_")
}
```

Comment: It is working fine for me `strsplit(filenames[2], "_")[[1]][2]
[1] "Nice"`

Comment: What about `Pretty_Place`?  Is it a single string

Comment: It would be better if you can show the expected output

Comment: See above, I hope I made it more clear.

Comment: I updated the asnswer.  please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("^[^_]+_(.*Place\\d*).*", "\\1", filenames[2])
#[1] "Nice_Place1"
```

Comment: Yes sorry, that was a mistake, i edited it. My problem is that I want to automatically get "Nice" and "Place" when its the case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think its a step in the right direction, but I just want one single word, not a list.

Comment: @Mr.Spock  It is not a `list`, but a `vector` of elemewntss

Comment: @Mr.Spock  Do you want the output as `"Place1  Nice_Place  Pretty_Place Place2"`

Comment: Thanks, I found now a solution by myself, see the edit in my post. Maybe you know a more nice one?

Comment: @Mr.Spock  Your solution is only giving `Nice_Place1` and not extracting other 'Place'

Comment: Yes that is what I want. Sorry when I didnt make it clear. I only want to get this one word.

Comment: @Mr.Spock  In that case you can just use `sub` on that element

Comment: You mean cutting out the letters? That doesnt work for me, I have a lot of data and the names are not 100% of same length.

Comment: @Mr.Spock  I am not sure.  Your `strsplit` is done on the second filename,  here I used `sub` on the same element and got the same output.  Sorry, I am done here

Comment: Ah ok, now I see. I didnt see you updated your answer. Thanks! Thats working!